# Dependencies in AngularJS App Level Module necessary or automatable?

Tags: angularjs

I started a project form the Angular Seed Project.  I've done a few Angular projects before, but this is the first one I have setup from scratch.  I don't remember having to add new modules to the "app level module" before.  Seems like there is a way to automate this, but my Google-Fu is failing me.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to remove 'myApp.home' and such from app.js so that I don't have to always add new pages to the app.js.  I know some modules will need to go there, but adding every page there seems like a pain.  I already figured out how to automate adding the script references to index.html

```js
//////////////////// APP.JS ////////////////////

'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.home'
])

.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
}]);


//////////////////// HOME.JS ////////////////////

'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.home', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '../app/home/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    });
}])

.controller('HomeCtrl', [function () {

}]);
```

```html
<!---------- INDEX.HTML ---------->

<html>
<head>
  <title>My App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My App</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="home/home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


<!---------- HOME.HTML ---------->

<div>TEST</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you will not create a new module for each new page, but use myApp module, then you do not need to add it as dependency to the myApp module. Each page will have its own JS file:

```
//////////////////// HOME.JS ////////////////////
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
   .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider.when('/home', {
           templateUrl: '../app/home/home.html',
           controller: 'HomeCtrl'
       }
   );
}])
    .controller('HomeCtrl', [function () {

    }
]);
```